# Jlist and Jlabel to change views in one panel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jlist

guys. So we just started to design an Enrollment System GUI which we plan to finish in 3-4 months including its functionality. But right now we focus on design. We are students so our knowledge with JAVA swing is limited but I'm willing to learn all. I've attached a screenshot of a Frame from our project. I would like to know what to learn and if what we're trying to do is possible with the given design. 
1.) Can I use the JLabel on the left navbar to change views on panel everytime user clicks on it? If so, how? Can you give a 'basic' example. 
2.) Using a Jlist item, can we switch/change views on the panel to show different teacher information? Please provide basic example.

Thank you. I'd appreciate any response.

[image]

Comment: look into CardLayout

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Thanks. @ Bimde and @ MadProgrammer. CardLayout got me started. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To change the text on labels use

```
lbl.setText( "New message" );
```

To change images on labels use
`icon = new ImageIcon( "new image.png" );
img.setIcon( icon );`